# how to pass combo box data to textfield

Tags: extjs

Im working with combo box. How do I get the ID of the selected data to be pass on the other textfield...

here is my sample code.
this is my combo box field

```
        {
             fieldLabel: 'Country',
                        name: 'idCountry',
                        xtype: 'combo',
                        margin: '0 0 10',
                        labelAlign: 'right',
                        validateBlank: true,
                        displayField: 'countryName',
                        valueField: 'idCountry',
                        store: 'country.Country',

        },
```

and this is the code for textfield that I want the idCountry to be stored.

```
        {
           fieldLabel: 'Country Id',
                        name: 'temp_id_countrt',
                        xtype: 'textfield',
                        margin: '0 0 10',
                        labelAlign: 'right',
                        validateBlank: true,
        },
```

thanks and Regards.. Gar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   config: {
    idCountry: null,
},
constructor : function (config) {
    this.initConfig(config);
    this.callParent(arguments);
},

                    {
                        xtype: 'textfield',
                        name : 'id',
                        fieldLabel: 'Country Id',
                        value: this.getidCountry()
                    },
```